# Here Map iOS Swift Crashed After call NMAApplicationContext.set(appId:.. appCode:...)

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am new on using Here Map's tools (https://developer.here.com). Currently, I am trying to integrate here map tools into my iOS Swift 3 project. However, the first step is to announce my license key and app code that I obtained from here map website by using the following Swift 3 code in the AppDelegate.swift:

```
NMAApplicationContext.set(appId: kHelloMapAppID, appCode: kHelloMapAppCode)
```

It crashed my app with the following error messages:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]:
>   nil argument' First throw call stack: (0x18bed91b8 0x18a91055c
>   0x18bed9100 0x18be76444 0x10023fad0 0x100260480 0x10025f6a8
>   0x10025f918 0x1011d9258 0x1011d9218 0x1011e6aec 0x1011dcce0
>   0x1011e8e2c 0x1011e8b78 0x18af6b2a0 0x18af6ad8c) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The sample project that came with the here map SDK has the same problem.

Is there anyone knowing how to use the SDK?

Comment: you can go to exact place where it crashes and see which string is nil, because this is what error says

Comment: Hi, the line I posted above is where the app crashed. The SDK was downloaded from here map, I am not able to see what's inside the SDK, and, hence, I am not able to see which variable has nil value.  I need the tech support from here map and I was instructed to post the question here by the here map tech support website.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out what's going on. Except adding the NMAKit.framework into the Xcode environment, we also need to add the link of the bundle, NMABundle.bundle into the environment. The file resides at NMAKit.framework/Resources/NMABundle.bundle so the Xcode environment should have the links of two files:

ProjectName
         |
         ProjectName
         |          |
         |          NMABundle.bundle
         |
         Frameworks
                    |
                     NMAKit.framework
                     ....